# Does WHERE condition scan the entire table?

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql, writing a query with WHERE condition on a table with thousands of records,  can it slow down the server or the program?

Eg : `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = 5;`

Comment: use indexes to overcome this problem

Comment: Show the table structure

Comment: Indexes means ? Im little bit new to mysql

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp

Answer (score 4):

By "default" it would.

One exception is when you have an index on a column.  Typically, a column called `id` would be a primary key -- which generates an index.  In that case, the query would be very fast.

Another exception would be if there table were partitioned by `id`.  Then only one partition would be read.

And, if the query had a `limit 1`, then the query would read the table until it found a match, then it would stop.

So, a `where` clause does not always scan the entire table.

Comment: You can check the usage of indexes, by using `EXPLAIN` in front of your query. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html